# Get the value of a key that its part of the properties of a class

Tags: python

When i try to get the value of "h"

```
class Humanoid():
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = {"h":1, "a":2, "l":2}
        self.needs = ["n"]
        self.move = False
```

Using the .get method

```
nn = Humanoid.body.get("h")
```

i get this error

`nn = Humanoid.body.get("h")
AttributeError: type object 'Humanoid' has no attribute 'body'`

Comment: body is an instance attribute

Comment: need to instantiate the object otherwise make it a class attribute to access it the other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to instantiate the class object.

```
human = Humanoid()

human.body.get("h")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, `body` is an instance attribute so you need to instantiate the class to access its instance attributes:

```
class Humanoid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = {"h": 1, "a": 2, "l": 2}
        self.needs = ["n"]
        self.move = False

humanoid = Humanoid()
print(humanoid.body.get("h"))
```

Or convert the instance attribute to a class attribute, like :

```
class Humanoid:
    body = {"h": 1, "a": 2, "l": 2}

    def __init__(self):
        self.needs = ["n"]
        self.move = False

print(Humanoid.body.get("h"))
```